# time limit exceeded hacker rank - max profit if know future prices

Tags: python, algorithm

I had an hacker rank challenge to find max profit given future stock prices in a array
eg) given [1, 2, 3, 1] The code should buy a share at 1, at 2, and sell at 3, nothing at 1(no point to buy if no future time to sell). The code would return the profit so 3 because you should buy one share at 1 and 2 (profit=-3) then sell both shares at 3(3*2=6) giving total profit of 3.

I passed few test cases but got time limit exceeded for most. I was wondering how I could improve this code to be more efficient and how a company would criticize my answer. I am a recent chemical engineering graduate with some courses in computer science, I am not sure what would be expected of me in the 25 min to complete this challenge.

```
def maximumProfit(price):
    # navigating left to right, if there is a larger number down the line, then buy
    #at each price buy unless there is a future higher price
    profit=0
    shares=0
    for i in range(len(price)):#our current price 
        buy=False #by default we are not buying and selling 0 shares
        for j in range(i,len(price)): #checking future price
        #starting at current price, traverse list 
            if price[j]>price[i]:#future price > current price
                buy=True 
                #since higher price detected we will buy at current price i index
        if buy == True:
            profit=profit-price[i]
            shares+=1
        else:#we are selling 
            profit=profit+price[i]*shares
            shares=0
    return profit
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and helping!

Comment: What are the exact limits on buying and selling?

Comment: For external questions, please include the link and/or complete req.

Comment: Replace the second ```for``` with ```max()``` You can use a ```slice``` as the arg to max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stockmax/problem.

Observation 1: For each stock you buy, you should sell it at the highest price in the future.

Obvservation 2: If there is no higher price for a stock,  you shouldn't buy it.

I will discuss two solutions: an `O(n log n)` one and `O(n)` one, both of which can pass the problem linked above (if written in C++, I'm not sure about python).

First you can notice observation 1 can be implemented with a multiset (balanced binary search tree or red-black tree is also fine). Put all the elements into a multiset, and for each element you process, pop it out of the multiset; then search the multiset for the largest element, where you will sell it at if the profit generated is greater than 0.

The `O(n)` solution would be to process the array from right to left. Maintain a variable `curmax` which is the largest variable. For each element:

if `curmax` is larger than current element, `ans += curmax - current element`.

else don't do anything.

update curmax with the current element, `curmax = max(curmax, current element)`.

Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader. (since I don't know python)

Comment: The O(n) solution is correct. The other solution doesn't work, because a binary search can't be used to find the highest peak in a series of peaks.

Comment: @user3386109 I am not trying to find the highest peak; instead, I am trying to find the maximum value. It has nothing to do with peaks

Comment: [An array of stock prices has peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJmQT.png), because the values in the array are not sorted. If they were sorted, the maximum would be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is already selected another answer, but...
I left the print's there so you can see it work.

```
def maximumProfit(prices):  # prices is a list
    profit = 0
    shares = 0
    for i in range(len(prices)):
        print '----',i,prices[i],prices[i:],max(prices[i:]),shares,profit
        if prices[i] < max(prices[i:]):
            profit -= prices[i]  # buy one
            shares += 1
            print 'buy ',i,prices[i],prices[i:],max(prices[i:]),shares,profit
        else:
            profit += shares * prices[i]  # sell all
            shares = 0
            print 'sell',i,prices[i],prices[i:],max(prices[i:]),shares,profit
    print shares, profit
    return profit

print maximumProfit([1,2,3,1])
print maximumProfit([4,2,3,4])
```